# Ms Excel : Need to replace last character and make single list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have problem in replacing last character in excel sheet.

for example

```
input1: 34553CHP01A , input2: C

output: 34553CHP01A
        34553CHP01B
        34553CHP01C
```

```
input: columnA,columnB, output: columnC
```

i have to replace multiple rows like this.

kindly help me. thanks.....

Comment: Hi @boss ,,, better share the formula you have tried so far & the result getting, will help us to understand your need to fix it !!

Comment: i tried last digit only replaced = if(len(b2),substitute(a2,right(a2,len(b2)),b2,"")

Comment: i don't know how to add inbetween characters.

Comment: ,, still is confusing better share the screen shot along with Input & output, the formula you have used is for nothing,,, better use `REPLACE` !

Comment: If you are going to stick with native worksheet functions, REPLACE would be better than SUBSTITUTE.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this *User Defined Function* code in a standard public module code sheet then use it as you would any native Excel function on the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Function EXPAND_PARTNO(pno As String, n As String, _
                       Optional delim As String = " ")

    Dim m As String, i As Long, pnos As Variant

    pno = Trim(pno)
    m = Right(pno, 1)
    pno = Left(pno, Len(pno) - 1)
    ReDim pnos(Asc(m) To Asc(n))

    For i = Asc(m) To Asc(n)
        pnos(i) = pno & Chr(i)
    Next i

    EXPAND_PARTNO = Join(pnos, delim)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This method working fine, How to list the result one by one in same column.

Comment: how to extend  upto 3 digit

Answer (score 0):

If one has TEXTJOIN then one can use:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(" ",,LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)&CHAR(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,CODE(RIGHT(A2))):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,CODE(B2)))))
```

Depending on one's version of Excel this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If one wants the values below each other in the same cell then change the `" "` to `CHAR(10)`

[image]

If they are to be in separate cells one below the other and one has the dynamic array formulas the just put this in the top cell:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)&CHAR(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,CODE(RIGHT(A2))):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,CODE(B2))))
```

And Excel will spill down.

[image]

---

If not and the user wants to fill down then put this in the first cell and copy/drag down:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($ZY:$ZY,CODE(RIGHT($A$2))))+ROW($A1)-1<=ROW(INDEX($ZY:$ZY,CODE($B$2))), LEFT($A$2,LEN($A$2)-1)&CHAR(ROW(INDEX($ZY:$ZY,CODE(RIGHT($A$2))))+ROW($A1)-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: TEXTJOIN not found in my excel version

Comment: Then use one of the other options given